# How to parse an integer in a glib string (gchar *)?

Tags: c, string, glib, atoi

I have a string which contains (the digits of) an integer value, and I want to obtain this value as an int. I am aware that there are other methods for doing this such as `atoi()`; however, I'd really like to use glib to do this. Does such a parsing/conversion function exist?

Comment: Do you mean to convert a string to an int or a pointer to an int?

Comment: I mean convert a string to an int.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GLib provides much of the standard C library with safety checks for input, and enhancements where practical.

The function you're looking for is [`g_ascii_strtoll()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-strtoll).

**Pedantic addendum**

`atoi()` treats locale the same way as `strtol` AND `g_ascii_strtoll()`. A very careful reading of the manpages and Glib documentation will reveal this. Here are some snippets for those that can't [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM):

[`atoi()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)

*The atoi() function converts the initial portion of the string  pointed to by nptr to int.  The behavior is the same as `strtol(nptr, (char **) NULL, 10);` except that atoi() does not detect errors.*

[`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

*In  locales  other  than  the  "C"  locale,  other  strings may also be accepted. (For example, the thousands separator of the current locale may be supported.)*

[`g_ascii_strtoll()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-ascii-strtoll)

*Converts a string to a gint64 value. This function behaves like the standard strtoll() function does in the C locale. It does this without actually changing the current locale, since that would not be thread-safe.*

**Changing locale**

If this is not sans-locale enough, you can set the locale through environment variables, and/or explicit calls to [`setlocale()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale)

Comment: That's actually the wrong answer. g_ascii_strtoll() isn't an enhancement of atoi() or strtoll(), it's a locale-independent version. The g_ascii_strtoll() docs say:

"To handle input from the user you should normally use the locale-sensitive system strtoll() function."

ntd's answer was correct, just use atoi() to convert a string to an int. It's not a GLib function, but that's okay.

Comment: hey, he doesn't mention locale requirements, and if locale isn't an issue, the default will be just fine. :)

Comment: That's the point, you never know when locale will be an issue. I don't know exactly how the function differs from locale to locale, but I can imagine that in, say, the Korean locale it might not convert Arabic numerals at all...

Comment: Exactly. And g_ascii_strtoll() won't do that. My point is that g_ascii_strtoll() isn't a drop-in replacement for strtoll() or atoi() with safety checks or enhancements, it's an entirely different function with a different purpose. So the answer to the OP's question, "is there a GLib function that replaces atoi()," is "no," which was ntd's answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry if you found me annoying.

Comment: Don't worry, ptomato. Being pedantic is great virtue for developers. Just gotta avoid being argumentative, annoying, and unproductive, it's a fine line, and a difficult skill to master.

Answer (score 4):

GLib is a general purpose library that provides a common base to develop applications. This does not mean GLib reimplements all the standard C library, but instead abstracts whatever not available (or not consistent) across all the supported platforms.

So, in short, you must use the standard `atoi()` function: GLib implements only the `gdouble` and `gint64` variants.